# How do you select a specific cell on a specific sheet excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I've been messing with VBA within an Excel module (as opposed to a sheet). I've been trying to select the last value in a table after importing data. 
 Below are two attempts at doing so:

**1st Try:**

```
Sheets("Awaiting Completion").Range("A" & rowno).Select
```

**2nd Try**

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Awaiting Completion").Range("A999").End(xlUp).Select
```

Both of these come back with:

"Run-time error '1004': Select method of Range class failed"

Comment: You `Activate` the sheet first.

Comment: From the linked thread: "Even better is using references and trying to avoid using the Selection and Active* objects entirely"

Comment: Also see how and why you should [avoid using Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).